# Continuous integration with CruiseControl.NET -> Automated Installation

Tags: svn

We already have SubVersion up and running for some time. Now's the question to implement Continuous Integration via CruiseControl.NET. But I was wondering if there weren't any tools to facilitate this installation. Unfortunatly we don't want to spend the money (yet) on buying TeamCity C.I., which also replaces CC.NET.
Anyway, we have A LOT of projects and solutions (sln2008) and I'd prefer to not set up everything manually, one by one.
What are your propositions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is not clear -- what's "wrong" with CC.NET? What goals are you trying to achieve?

Comment: From what I read, he wants a way to automate the setting up of existing projects in CC

Comment: What I want to do is automate the setup thats it automatically add the existing repo's. Now you have the add every repo manually and give a 1000 settings each (often already configured in Svn itself)

Answer (score 1):

If all your solutions have the same configuration for CC.net, you could write a tool to loop through your subversion repo and create some ccnet.config file based on a template, since the cruise control configuration is XML based.

Since different projects could have drastically different needs (build targets, nant tests, log paths, test cases, etc) i'm not sure how a 'generic' tool would possibly sort all that out for you, without you still having to go through the configuration and tweak each one.  On the plus side, setting up the bulk of the configuration should be a 1-time thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering each project / solution will have it's own requirements with regards to CI, you will have to do this by hand for each of them.

There's no real way to automate that.